# Hard disk raid data lost after restart

Tags: 12.04, raid

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and two disks working via raid. In BIOS I have set them up to use raid. After I restart computer all data changes are lost. I had these drives in another computer, and they worked fine there.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the drives back on the original controller and you do not have a backup of your files - which you should have - then R-Studio might help you here.

[R-Studio](http://www.r-studio.com/)

But if you can change back to the old controller - and you love your data - then this would be easier and more reliable than using a software to fix arrays ...

Good Luck!